# How can I parse data for parseJSON?

Tags: haskell

I have a data which I want to parse from json:

```
data MyData = MyData 
    { myDataId :: UUID 
    , myDataVar1 :: Bool
    , myDataVar2 :: Maybe (UUID, String)
    }

instance FromJSON MyData where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    MyData <$> v .: "id"
        <*> v .: "var1"
        <*> ((,) <$> ((v .: "var2") >>= (.: "id")) <*> ((v .: "var2") >>= (.: "name"))) --- ??? doesn't work
```

How can I parse myDataVar2?

Comment: Reuse the pre-existing Maybe and tuple instances.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, how?

Comment: "Doesn't work" - how so? Does it compile? Is the runtime behaviour different that expected?

Comment: By calling `parseJSON` within.

Comment: @dfeuer, for which part of it?

Comment: @Mario your inner object (`var2` from what I can guess) - btw: it would help if you just add a small example of you input-JSON ^^

Comment: @Carsten: `{ "id" :"GA23210X", "var1": false, "var2": null}` and `{ "id" :"A211MNLR", "var1": false, "var2": { "id": "GA23210X", "name": "child"} }`. Or something similar, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this based on the *suspected* JSON @zeta gave and the idea of @dfeuer

here is a compiling/working example

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module ParseJson where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Encoding
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (fromStrict)

testData :: Text
testData = "{ \"id\" :\"A211MNLR\", \"var1\": false, \"var2\": { \"id\": \"GA23210X\", \"name\": \"child\"} }"

testData2 :: Text
testData2 = "{ \"id\" :\"GA23210X\", \"var1\": false, \"var2\": null}"

data MyData = MyData 
    { myDataId :: Text
    , myDataVar1 :: Bool
    , myDataVar2 :: Maybe (Text, Text)
    } deriving Show

instance FromJSON MyData where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    MyData <$> v .: "id"
           <*> v .: "var1"
           <*> (v .:? "var2" >>= parsePair)
    where parsePair (Just (Object o)) = Just <$> ((,) <$> o .: "id" <*> o.: "name")
          parsePair _                 = pure Nothing

parse :: Text -> Maybe MyData
parse = decode . fromStrict . encodeUtf8
```

here are the tests:

```
λ> parse testData
Just (MyData {myDataId = "A211MNLR", myDataVar1 = False, myDataVar2 = Just ("GA23210X","child")})
λ> parse testData2
Just (MyData {myDataId = "GA23210X", myDataVar1 = False, myDataVar2 = Nothing})
```

#### remarks

- I used `Text` instead of `UUID` - as far as I can see there is a `fromText` in the `uuid` package you can use to transform it further (but it's a `Maybe UUID` as well) or you could write the `FromJSON` instance for it - sadly I have no time to do it right - sorry :(
- it's not pretty and there is probably an operator for what I did with `parsePair` already there

but it should be a start for you to figure it out